# Why am I getting "Class 'app\models\Yii' not found" error?

Tags: php, yii2

Model's function for which I got this error:

```
public function setPassword($password)
{
    $this->password_hash = Yii::$app->security->generatePasswordHash($password);
}

public function generateAuthKey()
{
    $this->auth_key = Yii::$app->security->generateRandomString();
}
```

Comment: I'm assuming you're in the `app\models` namespace and haven't added a `use` statement for `\Yii`. See http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/basics.namespace#c10572

Comment: so what do i do use ...... what else..

Comment: check this out <a href="http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22605235/yii2-gii-crud-error-class-app-models-yii-not-found">link</a>

Answer (score 9):

Add

```
use Yii;
```

Before your class declaration.

Or add a backslash in front of the Yii word.

```
$this->password_hash = \Yii::$app-> ...
```

Answer (score 0):

Just add

use Yii;

at the top of your controller before the class and it will work fine

Comment: Welcome on SO. Did you notice that you posted the exact (but less detailed) answer than this one? https://stackoverflow.com/a/32985672/4862968